# difference between context-param and env-entry in web.xml

Tags: java-ee-6, web.xml, servlet-3.0

I know, env-entry uses jndi and can be changed during runtime, where context-param cannot.

However, I can inject the values of both via @Resource, where type conversion is made automatically.

What is the difference (pros/cons) of using context-param or env-entry in web.xml.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196868/servlet-spec-context-param-vs-env-entry