# Specify a `DataSource` factory instead of Tomcat's default

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jndi, objectfactory

## tl;dr

How do I tell Tomcat 9 to use a [Postgres-specific](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/common/PGObjectFactory.html) [object factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/spi/ObjectFactory.html?is-external=true) for producing [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object in response to [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) query?

## Details

I can easily get a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object from [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) 9 by defining an XML file named the same as my context. For example, for a web-app named `clepsydra`, I create this file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Domain: DEV, TEST, ACPT, ED, PROD  -->
    <Environment name = "work.basil.example.deployment-mode"
                 description = "Signals whether to run this web-app with development, testing, or production settings."
                 value = "DEV"
                 type = "java.lang.String"
                 override = "false"
                 />

    <Resource
                name="jdbc/postgres"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb"
                user="myuser"
                password="mypasswd"
                />
</Context>
```

I place that file in my Tomcat “base” folder, in `conf` folder, in folders I created with engine name `Catalina` and host name `localhost`. Tomcat feeds settings into a resource factory to return an instance of `DataSource`. I can access that instance via JNDI:

```
Context ctxInitial = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = 
        ( DataSource ) ctxInitial.lookup( "java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres" )
;
```

I do realize that `postgres` in that lookup string could be something more specific to a particular app. But let's go with `postgres` for the same of demonstration.

### I want `org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource`, not `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`

This setup is using [Tomcat’s own resource factory for JDBC DataSource objects](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources). The underlying class of the returned `DataSource` class is `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`. Unfortunately, I do not want a `DataSource` of that class. I want a `DataSource` of the class provided by the [JDBC driver from *The PostgreSQL Global Development Group*](https://jdbc.postgresql.org): [`org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.html).

By reading the Tomcat documentation pages, [*JNDI Resources How-To*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) and [*JNDI Datasource How-To*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html), I came to realize that Tomcat allows us to use an alternate factory for these `DataSource` objects in place of the default factory implementation bundled with Tomcat. Sounds like what I need.

### `PGObjectFactory`

I discovered that the Postgres JDBC driver already comes bundled with such implementations:

- [`PGObjectFactory`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/common/PGObjectFactory.html)
  For simple JDBC connections.
- [`PGXADataSourceFactory`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/xa/PGXADataSourceFactory.html)
  For [XA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA)-enabled `DataSource` implementation, for distributed transactions.

By the way, there is a similar factory built into the driver for OSGi apps, [`PGDataSourceFactory`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/osgi/PGDataSourceFactory.html). I assume that is of no use to me with Tomcat.

So, the `PGObjectFactory` class implements the interface [`javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/spi/ObjectFactory.html?is-external=true) required by JNDI.

#### SPI

I am guessing that the `spi` in that package name means the object factories load via the [*Java Service Provider Interface (SPI)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface).

[image: screenshot of location of SPI mapping file, and its contents]

So I presume that need a SPI mapping file, as discussed in the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) and in the [Vaadin documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-service-init-listener.html). added a `META-INF` folder to my Vaadin `resources` folder, and created a `services` folder further nested there. So in `/resources/META-INF/services` I created a file named `javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory` containing a single line of text, the name of my desired object factory: `org.postgresql.ds.common.PGObjectFactory`. I even checked inside the Postgres JDBC driver to verify physically the existence and the fully-qualified name of this class.

## Question

➥ My question is: How do I **tell Tomcat to use `PGObjectFactory` rather than its default object factory** for producing my `DataSource` objects for producing connections to my Postgres database?

#### `factory` attribute on `<Resource>` element

I had hoped it would be as simple as adding a `factory` attribute (`factory="org.postgresql.ds.common.PGObjectFactory"`) to my `<Resource>` element seen above. I got this idea from the Tomcat page, [*The Context Container*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Definitions). That page is quite confusing as it focuses on global resource, but I do not need or want to define this `DataSource` globally. I need this `DataSource` only for my one web app.

Adding that `factory` attribute:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Domain: DEV, TEST, ACPT, ED, PROD  -->
    <Environment name = "work.basil.example.deployment-mode"
                 description = "Signals whether to run this web-app with development, testing, or production settings."
                 value = "DEV"
                 type = "java.lang.String"
                 override = "false"
                 />

    <Resource
                name="jdbc/postgres"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb"
                user="myuser"
                password="mypasswd"
                factory="org.postgresql.ds.common.PGObjectFactory"
                />
</Context>
```

…fails with my `DataSource` object being null.

```
ctxInitial = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = ( DataSource ) ctxInitial.lookup( "java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres" );
System.out.println( "dataSource = " + dataSource );
```

> null

Removing that `factory="org.postgresql.ds.common.PGObjectFactory"` attribute resolves the exception. But then I am back to getting a Tomcat `BasicDataSource` rather than a Postgres `PGSimpleDataSource`. Thus my Question here.

I know my `Context` XML is being loaded successfully because I can access that `Environment` entry’s value.

### 2nd experiment

I tried this from the top, days later.

I created a new "Plain Java Servlet" flavor Vaadin 14.0.9 project named "datasource-object-factory".

Here is my entire Vaadin web app code. The bottom half is the JNDI lookup.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@Route ( "" )
@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{

    public MainView ( )
    {
        Button button = new Button( "Click me" ,
                event -> Notification.show( "Clicked!" ) );


        Button lookupButton = new Button( "BASIL - Lookup DataSource" );
        lookupButton.addClickListener( ( ClickEvent < Button > buttonClickEvent ) -> {
            Notification.show( "BASIL - Starting lookup." );
            System.out.println( "BASIL - Starting lookup." );
            this.lookupDataSource();
            Notification.show( "BASIL - Completed lookup." );
            System.out.println( "BASIL - Completed lookup." );
        } );

        this.add( button );
        this.add( lookupButton );
    }

    private void lookupDataSource ( )
    {
        Context ctxInitial = null;
        try
        {
            ctxInitial = new InitialContext();

            // Environment entry.
            String deploymentMode = ( String ) ctxInitial.lookup( "java:comp/env/work.basil.example.deployment-mode" );
            Notification.show( "BASIL - deploymentMode: " + deploymentMode );
            System.out.println( "BASIL - deploymentMode = " + deploymentMode );

            // DataSource resource entry.
            DataSource dataSource = ( DataSource ) ctxInitial.lookup( "java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres" );
            Notification.show( "BASIL - dataSource: " + dataSource );
            System.out.println( "BASIL - dataSource = " + dataSource );
        }
        catch ( NamingException e )
        {
            Notification.show( "BASIL - NamingException: " + e );
            System.out.println( "BASIL - NamingException: " + e );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To keep things simple, I did not designate a Tomcat "base" folder, instead going with defaults. I did not run from IntelliJ, instead moving my web app’s WAR file manually to the `webapps` folder.

I downloaded a new version of Tomcat, version 9.0.27. I dragged in the Postgres JDBC jar to the `/lib` folder. I used the BatChmod app to set the permissions of the Tomcat folder.

To the `conf` folder, I created the `Catalina` & `localhost` folders. In there I created a file named `datasource-object-factory.xml` with the same contents as seen above.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Domain: DEV, TEST, ACPT, ED, PROD  -->
    <Environment name = "work.basil.example.deployment-mode"
                 description = "Signals whether to run this web-app with development, testing, or production settings."
                 value = "DEV"
                 type = "java.lang.String"
                 override = "false"
                 />

    <Resource
                factory="org.postgresql.ds.common.PGObjectFactory"
                name="jdbc/postgres"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb"
                user="myuser"
                password="mypasswd"
                />
</Context>
```

I copied my web app’s `datasource-object-factory.war` file to `webapps` in Tomcat. Lastly, I run Tomcat's `/bin/startup.sh` and watch the WAR file explode into a folder.

With the `factory="org.postgresql.ds.common.PGObjectFactory"` attribute on my `Resource` element, the resulting `DataSource` is `null`.

As with my first experiment, I can access the value of the `<Environment>`, so I know my context-name XML file is being found and processes successfully via JNDI.

Here are the logs on a Google Drive:

- [catalina.out](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nAekGy4rJNCgjLAP21M9M6Qan0T8EOmI)
- [catalina.2019-10-18.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-5wBpWCsy6SPbMwY8iGWKbH58dfE4x2m)

Comment: Throws an exception such as what? NB You found it [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Definitions): described but not documented in the tables.

Comment: But according to the document I cited and that you appear to be referencing, what you did should work. So why it didn't work *is* relevant. But if you don't want further help, by all means don't answer.

Comment: @user207421 My exception occurred when I added a `factory` attribute due to a vague recollection of having seen that used somewhere. The page you linked does not say anything about a `factory` attribute on the `Resource` element. So I do not understand why you said “what you did should work”. What I did is not discussed in that documentation.

Comment: The page I linked *gives an example* of exactly that. That's why I said 'described but not documented in the tables'. You can take the fairly trivial step of posting the exception, or you can keep arguing, but I warn you I will lose interest rapidly.

Comment: @user207421 I was wrong about an Exception being thrown. That exception came from my web-app failing due to my expected `DataSource` object being `null`. I also tried adding an SPI mapping for the object factory, but no help there. I revised my Question with these details. I appreciate your attention and help.

Comment: The `factory` should be working. When it *doesn't* work, do you get any errors or warnings in your log file? I would expect to see something in `logs/catalina.out`.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I posted two logs to a Google Drive. The only error of interest I noticed is: `18-Oct-2019 18:31:50.090 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent Cannot register null bean for [Catalina:type=DataSource,host=localhost,context=/datasource-object-factory,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/postgres"]`

Comment: Related: [*“<Parameter>” versus “<Environment>” entries in a Tomcat Context*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58372785/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resource configuration seems to need modification. As mentioned in [Tomcat Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Definitions),

> You can declare the characteristics of the resource to be returned for JNDI lookups of  and  elements in the web application deployment descriptor. ***You MUST also define the needed resource parameters as attributes of the Resource element, to configure the object factory*** to be used (if not known to Tomcat already), and the properties used to configure that object factory.

The reason you are getting null, is the object factory cannot determine the type of object it needs to create, refer [PGObjectFactory code](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/ds/common/PGObjectFactory.java)

```java
public Object getObjectInstance ( Object obj , Name name , Context nameCtx ,
                                  Hashtable < ?, ? > environment ) throws Exception
{
    Reference ref = ( Reference ) obj;
    String className = ref.getClassName();
    // Old names are here for those who still use them
    if ( 
            className.equals( "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" )
            || className.equals( "org.postgresql.jdbc2.optional.SimpleDataSource" )
            || className.equals( "org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3SimpleDataSource" ) 
    )
    {
        return loadSimpleDataSource( ref );
    } else if ( 
            className.equals( "org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource" )
            || className.equals( "org.postgresql.jdbc2.optional.ConnectionPool" )
            || className.equals( "org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3ConnectionPool" ) 
    )
    {
        return loadConnectionPool( ref );
    } else if ( 
            className.equals( "org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource" )
            || className.equals( "org.postgresql.jdbc2.optional.PoolingDataSource" )
            || className.equals( "org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PoolingDataSource" ) 
    )
    {
        return loadPoolingDataSource( ref );
    } else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The value 'javax.sql.DataSource' in the resource definition does not correspond to any of the class the object factory understands, use one of the classes the object factory understands, in your case 'org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource'.

However, this will still not get you a valid data source, reason being, refer, in the same source code, the following sections:

```java
private Object loadSimpleDataSource(Reference ref) {
    PGSimpleDataSource ds = new PGSimpleDataSource();
    return loadBaseDataSource(ds, ref);
}
```

and

```java
protected Object loadBaseDataSource(BaseDataSource ds, Reference ref) {
    ds.setFromReference(ref);

    return ds;
}
```

The `loadBaseDataSource` calls `setFromReference` on the super class of all data sources, refer: [`BaseDataSource`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/ds/common/BaseDataSource.java), section:

```java
public void setFromReference ( Reference ref )
{
    databaseName = getReferenceProperty( ref , "databaseName" );
    String portNumberString = getReferenceProperty( ref , "portNumber" );
    if ( portNumberString != null )
    {
        String[] ps = portNumberString.split( "," );
        int[] ports = new int[ ps.length ];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < ps.length ; i++ )
        {
            try
            {
                ports[ i ] = Integer.parseInt( ps[ i ] );
            }
            catch ( NumberFormatException e )
            {
                ports[ i ] = 0;
            }
        }
        setPortNumbers( ports );
    } else
    {
        setPortNumbers( null );
    }
    setServerNames( getReferenceProperty( ref , "serverName" ).split( "," ) );

    for ( PGProperty property : PGProperty.values() )
    {
        setProperty( property , getReferenceProperty( ref , property.getName() ) );
    }
}
```

The above requires three properties viz. 'databaseName', 'portNumber' and 'serverName', so these properties also need to be on the resource definition.

Sum total, your resource declaration probably should look as follows:

```xml
<Resource
            factory="org.postgresql.ds.common.PGObjectFactory"
            name="jdbc/postgres"
            auth="Application"
            type="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
            serverName="127.0.0.1"
            portNumber="5432"
            databaseName="mydb"
            />
```

You should then resolve the data source as you have already done and get the connection with getConnection(userName, pwd).

NOTE: You could also set 'userName' and 'password' property, defined in  `BaseDataSource`.

Putting that all together, we can revise your original example to look like the following. We use some of the [`DataSource` configuration properties defined by the Postgres JDBC driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ds-ds.html).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

    <!-- Domain: DEV, TEST, ACPT, ED, PROD  -->
    <Environment name = "work.basil.example.deployment-mode"
                 description = "Signals whether to run this web-app with development, testing, or production settings."
                 value = "DEV"
                 type = "java.lang.String"
                 override = "false"
                 />

    <!-- `DataSource` object for obtaining database connections to Postgres  -->
    <Resource
                factory="org.postgresql.ds.common.PGObjectFactory"
                type="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
                auth="Container"

                driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                name="jdbc/postgres"

                serverName="127.0.0.1"
                portNumber="5432"
                databaseName="myDb"

                user="myuser"
                password="mypasswd"

                ssl="false"
                />

</Context>
```

Comment: Yes! That worked. Thank you so much. I spent many hours wrestling this problem. Hopefully this page will help others as well. Such a simple solution, but not at all obvious from reading the documentation.